# What is this port on the back of my Samsung washing machine? It leaks a little bit of water at the end of the cycle

Tags: washing-machine, samsung

I noticed that my Samsung Washing Machine is leaking at the end of the cycle from this port. Any idea what this port is?

[image]

Comment: It looks like an alternate drain-hose port. If you have the **model number**, find it in the owner's manual, online if the paper one is lost.

Answer (score 8):

This is an air vent. The door on a front loader is sealed so that water won't leak out, so a separate vent is provided to allow air to move in and out of the washer when it fills, when it empties and when you open the door. Without a vent, air pressure would build up when the washer fills with water, a vacuum would form when the washer empties and the door would be difficult to open due to a suction effect.

Front loaders have an inner and outer tub. This vent is connected to the top of the outer tub by a flexible rubber duct. At the point of connection, there is a device called a mushroom valve which looks like a mushroom whose stem sits in a hole and whose cap can move up and down. When air wants to leave the outer tub, the mushroom valve does not interfere, but when water or suds try to leave, they force the mushroom's cap upwards, and the cap momentarily seals the air exit point at the air duct. This is intended to prevent sloshing water at the very end of a spin cycle from coming out of the vent. (At the very end because in slowing down to a stop, the spin can turn into violent shaking for a few moments, slinging a little water out of the vent.)

Suds, fabric softener and / or grit can gum up the stem of the mushroom valve, making it hard to move so that it does not rise up to close when water hits it.

To fix the problem, unplug the washer, remove the top by removing 4 screws at the back of the top, slide the top toward the rear, then lift the top straight up. You will see the flexible rubber duct going from the vent to the top of the outer tub. Loosen the clamp that holds the rubber duct to the tub and remove the duct. You'll see the top of the mushroom right there. Use a piece of sticky tape to pull the mushroom out of its housing. Wash the mushroom cap and stem and clean out the hole where the stem goes using cotton swabs, pipe cleaners or the like. Re-insert the mushroom and make sure it can move freely. Re-install the clamp on the rubber duct, replace the top, plug in the washer and enjoy leak-free washing.